# Messagebox name is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

When I create a couple of definitions in between each other, it sometimes doesn't see the `import`s, such as massege box, destroy from tkinter, and sleep command from time. It's been a week since I started learning python and I don't know how to fix it.

Error for the `destroy()` command :

```
    File "C:\Users\enes baba\Desktop\animemusic\test.py", line 58, in roll
    destroy()

NameError: name 'destroy' is not defined
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Error for the `sleep()` command :

```
  File C:\Users\enes baba\Desktop\animemusic\test.py", line 77, in <lambda>
    Button(page_play, text="Roll The Dice", command=lambda: roll()).place(x=50, y=100)
  File "C:\Users\enes baba\Desktop\animemusic\test.py", line 56, in roll
    sleep(5)
NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined
```

The code:

```
def open21():

    global game
    global player_num
    global computer_num
    if pass_code != 1:
        messagebox.showerror("Login First", "You need to LOGIN first to be able to play.")
    if pass_code == 1:
        page_play = Toplevel()
        page_play.title("Play21")
        page_play.geometry("400x400")
        Label(page_play, text=player_num).place(x=20, y=10)
        Label(page_play, text=computer_num).place(x=90, y=10)

        def roll():
            import tkinter
            from tkinter import messagebox
            global player_num
            global computer_num
            player_num += random.randint(1, 10)
            Label(page_play, text=player_num).place(x=20, y=10)
            if player_num > 21:
                player_num = random.randint(1, 10)
                computer_num = random.randint(1, 10)
                messagebox.showerror("Lost", "You've exceeded 21. You've Lost The Game. Try Again")
                sleep(5)
                # game = 2
                destroy(page_play)

        def pas():
            global player_num
            global computer_num
            while computer_num < 13:
                computer_num += random.randint(1, 10)
            while (21 - player_num) < (21 - computer_num):
                computer_num += random.randint(1, 10)
            Label(page_play, text=computer_num).place(x=90, y=10)
            # sleep(3)
            if computer_num > 21:
                messagebox.showinfo("Won", "Congrats the computers number have exceeded 21. You won")
                destroy(page_play)
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("Won", "Congrats Your number is closer to 21. You won")
                # sleep(2)
                destroy(page_play)

        Button(page_play, text="Roll The Dice", command=lambda: roll()).place(x=50, y=100)
        Button(page_play, text="Pass", command=lambda: pas()).place(x=150, y=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `destroy(page_play)` try

```py
page_play.destroy()
```

`destroy` is a method so you have to call it this way.

To get the sleep function to work, add

```py
from time import sleep
```